# How to label list elements?

Tags: list-manipulation, data

I have a list of lists. There are large number of elements in the list (I am showing here just a minimal example). I want to extract elements $d$ and $e$ from the data. So, I have to count at what position $d$ and $e$ are.

Is there any efficient way to do this without counting positions of elements manually? Can we label these elements and use those labels instead of using their positions?

```
a = RandomReal[{1, 100}, 10];
b = RandomReal[{1, 100}, 10];
c = RandomReal[{1, 100}, 10];
d = RandomReal[{1, 100}, 10];
e = RandomReal[{1, 100}, 10];
f = RandomReal[{1, 100}, 10];
data = Table[{a[[i]], b[[i]], c[[i]], d[[i]], e[[i]], f[[i]]}, {i, 1, 10}];
data1 = data[[All, {5, 6}]];
```

Comment: Lookup [`Transpose`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html?q=Transpose). It allows a more compact treatment:  `data = Transpose @ { a, b, c, d, e, f };` is equivalent to your *procedural* `Table` statement.

Comment: It would be really nice, if you could maybe say why the answer given is not acceptable. Thank your very much for the effort. :)

Answer (score 6):

Make use of [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html) or [`Dataset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset.html):

```
data = Query[Transpose] @ AssociationThread[
    CharacterRange["a", "f"] -> {a, b, c, d, e, f}
];

data // Dataset
```

[image: Dataset presentation of labeled data]

**Edit**

In case you wonder: Using `Transpose` on the `Association` created by `AssociationThread` will not work directly. Nesting the `Transpose` in [`Query`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Query.html) will make use of `AssociationTranspose` which is contained in the `GeneralUtilities` package:

```
Query[ Transpose ] // Normal
```

> GeneralUtilities`AssociationTranspose